PMPRO Membership level name on post thumbnails
I'm trying to add css3 corner ribbon with the paid memberships pro level name for each post in  acrhives, my function below is working fine on homepage but when I navigate to Wordpress category archive all posts shows the first level name even if the post has no membership level, also all posts are coming up with pmpro-has-access class as post class.
When I navigate to custom term or tag actives there is no output at all, so it works one homepage only.
I think the problem is here anywhere a part of my function which I got from pmpro plugin includes/content.php
if(isset($mypost->post_type) && $mypost->post_type == "post")
    {
        // Get the categories for this post.
        $post_terms = wp_get_post_categories( $mypost->ID );

        // Get the tags for this post.
        $post_terms = array_merge( $post_terms, wp_get_post_tags( $mypost->ID, array('fields' => 'ids' ) ) );

        if( ! $post_terms )
        {
            //just check for entries in the memberships_pages table
            $sqlQuery = "SELECT m.id, m.name FROM $wpdb->pmpro_memberships_pages mp LEFT JOIN $wpdb->pmpro_membership_levels m ON mp.membership_id = m.id WHERE mp.page_id = '" . esc_sql( $mypost->ID ) . "'";
        }
        else
        {
            //are any of the post categories associated with membership levels? also check the memberships_pages table
            $sqlQuery = "(SELECT m.id, m.name FROM $wpdb->pmpro_memberships_categories mc LEFT JOIN $wpdb->pmpro_membership_levels m ON mc.membership_id = m.id WHERE mc.category_id IN(" . implode(",", array_map( 'intval', $post_terms ) ) . ") AND m.id IS NOT NULL) UNION (SELECT m.id, m.name FROM $wpdb->pmpro_memberships_pages mp LEFT JOIN $wpdb->pmpro_membership_levels m ON mp.membership_id = m.id WHERE mp.page_id = '" . esc_sql( $mypost->ID ) . "')";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        //are any membership levels associated with this page?
        $sqlQuery = "SELECT m.id, m.name FROM $wpdb->pmpro_memberships_pages mp LEFT JOIN $wpdb->pmpro_membership_levels m ON mp.membership_id = m.id WHERE mp.page_id = '" . esc_sql( $mypost->ID ) . "'";
    }

Im getting the results with this code:
$post_membership_levels = $wpdb->get_results($sqlQuery);
foreach( $post_membership_levels as $level ) {
    if ( $opt['pmpro_ribbon'] == 1 ) {
      echo '<div class="ribbon-wrapper"><div class="ribbon ribbon-' . intval( $level->id ) . '">' . esc_html( $level->name ) . '</div></div>';
    }
  }

I don#t know what is wrong there must be any easier way to do this instead of using the db queries.
